# Two different icon shapes for linked/related questions in sidebar

Tags: bug, design

In the linked/related questions sidebar, there is an icon inconsistency. Questions with an accepted answer have a (green) **hexagonal** icon, and questions without an accepted answer have a (grey) **rectangular** icon. Is this a bug?

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: It doesn’t show on any of the other network sites, but I think it must be intentional, since it shows up on old pages in the Wayback Machine.

Comment: It's so you know which have accepted answers and which don't

Comment: Is this just asking why one has a shape and one doesn't (or is defaultish)?  I never really thought much of it, to be honest, since the function was clear.

Comment: Why not ask [Jin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/jin), who I believe was in charge of most of the site design?

Comment: That's our custom design. That's how accepted answers show up on SFF. That it shows if the answer is accepted with the green thing is universal.

Comment: I've actually seen some sites on the network (if I remember correctly) that have the same icon for questions with accepted answers and without accepted answers. They look bland and confusing.

Answer (score 4):

### This is [status-bydesign](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) (I think)

From the source of the webpage, we see that the accepted answer divs have the class

```
<div class="answer-votes answered-accepted default">8</div>
```

If one looks more closely at the image which is used as the background image for the class `answered-accepted` we find that it is the following:

[image: Hexagon accepted answer image]

Those on other sites do not have the hexagons, (at least not on Maths.SE) which may be to give a futuristic look to our site. As we are SFF.SE after all and sci-fi is a major part of our agenda.

The non-accepted answers have the class

```
<div class="answer-votes default">5</div>
```

With no background image.

Comment: Why do these source code lines make you think the shape difference is intentional? Wouldn't it also be possible (and probably more likely) that whoever implemented the hexagon simply overlooked the fact that a green *and* grey version was needed?

Comment: No, because otherwise why would the hexagons be attributed to the `answered-accepted` class and not just the `default` class or the `answer-votes` class.